# Take two characters from a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2003

In Cell A1 I have a date format: `22-12-2011` (dd-mm-yyy).

Now in `A2` I want to have only the `dd` of A1.

So I want to have 22. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to take only the day, use:

```
A2=DAY(A1)
```

In Cell A2 you have to type:

```
=DAY(A1)
```